# passing an input value directly into a function within a loop

Tags: vuejs2

So basically I have this;

```
    <ul class="queryView">
      <li
      v-for="(object, index) in Objects"
      >
        {{ object.key }}
        <input
        type="text"
        @input="saveValue(value)"

        >
      </li>
    </ul>
```

...

```
 saveValue(value){
    ... do somthing with value
  },
```

Since it's in a loop, v-model does not work as they will affect each looped element. i.e If in one input field I put in a word all of the fields will display the same word.

thus I need to get the input value directly into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-model` does work if properly used.

See this JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/167740/

But if you want to use a function to handle the values, it is also fine, but much more verbose.

See this JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/167731/

Comment: Thanks, the verbose way serves very well

Comment: Cool. whichever method you prefer is actually fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

See the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

> […] the method receives the native event as the only argument. If using inline statement, the statement has access to the special `$event` property: `v-on:click="handle('ok', $event)"`.

The [`"input"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has a [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, which in your case is your [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) element, on which you can read its current [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    saveValue(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      console.log(value);
    },
    otherMethod(text1, event) {
      console.log(text1);
      console.log(event.target.value);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in 3">
      {{i}}<input @input="saveValue" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    With inline statement:
    <input @input="otherMethod('other', $event)" />
  </p>
</div>
```